# How to set the different value to a property depending on user's input in reactJs

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have multiple input box with different names. While calling

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import cookie from 'react-cookie';
import Request from 'superagent';

export default class Performance extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
                fullName : cookie.load('fullName'),
                empId : cookie.load('empId'),
                userResults : [{
                    "sectionTitle": "Customer Orientation",
                    "isMandatory": 0,
                    "question": [{
                        "qusId": 1,
                        "question": "Number of customer ",
                        "weightage": 15,
                    }]
                }]
        }; 
        
    }
     handleChange(event) {
            this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});        
     }  

render() {
    
    return ( 
        <div >
             
            <div className="container ">
                <form className="form-signin1"> 
                    {  
                    this.state.userResults.map(function(res)
                    {
                        var questions = res.question.map(function(res1){
                            return (
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="textbox" value="" name={'ques_check_box_1_1'} onChange={(e) =>{this.handleChange.bind(this)}}/></td>
                                        <td><input type="textbox" value="" name={'ques_check_box_1_2'} onChange={(e) =>{this.handleChange.bind(this)}}/></td>
                                        <td><input type="textbox" value="" name={'ques_check_box_1_3'} onChange={(e) =>{this.handleChange.bind(this)}}/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            });
                        return (
                            <div className="row">        
                                <table className="table text-center" >
                                    <thead>
                                        <th width="400">Deliverables</th>
                                        <th>Justifications</th>
                                        <th>Weightage</th>
                                        <th className="lastHead">Employee <br />Weightage</th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {questions}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table> 
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                    }
                </form>
            </div> 
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

functions it through's error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleChange' of undefined at onChange". Please help me to solve.

Comment: Why is handleChange inside constructor?

Comment: sorry i have changed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `callback` methods in `map`, so you have to maintain the `context` also by using `.bind(this)` with `function`, or you can use `arrow functions`, it will do this job for you, you don't have to worry about `binding`, Try this:

```
this.state.userResults.map((res, i)=>
{
    var questions = res.question.map((res1,j)=>{
        return (
                <tr key={j}>
                    <td><input type="textbox" value="" name={'ques_check_box_1_1'} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/></td>
                    <td><input type="textbox" value="" name={'ques_check_box_1_2'} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>/></td>
                    <td><input type="textbox" value="" name={'ques_check_box_1_3'} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>/></td>
                </tr>
            )
        });
    return (
        <div className="row" key={i}>        
            <table className="table text-center" >
                <thead>
                    <th width="400">Deliverables</th>
                    <th>Justifications</th>
                    <th>Weightage</th>
                    <th className="lastHead">Employee <br />Weightage</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {questions}
                </tbody>
            </table> 
        </div>
    )
})
```

And in this part you are `binding` the `event` twice:

`onChange={(e) =>{this.handleChange.bind(this)}}`

either use it like this:

```
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
```

or

```
onChange={(e) =>{this.handleChange(e)}}
```

Suggestion: Assign unique `key` to each `element`, when creating the `ui` dynamically in loop.